# gnome-terminal - I have no name

Tags: ubuntu, samba, kerberos, gnome

## Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS x64
- HW: VM on vSphere with 2vCPU and 2GB Memory
- Default GNOME desktop installation with gnome-session-flashback
  3.8.0.
- Connected to AD domain using Samba and winbind (see files below).

## Issue:

Login etc. is successful, but when opening a gnome-terminal, sometimes there is `I have no name!@hostname:~$` instead of `username@hostname:~$`

## Facts:

- Can be easily reprocuded by opening e.g. 20 gnome-terminals (`for i in
  {1..20}; do gnome-terminal; done`)
- In the "failing" terminals, `whoami` reports the correct username and
  USER variable is set.
- Running the different commands (`whoami`, `wbinfo -m`, `getent passwd
  username`, `id username`) over a period of time (e.g. infinite for loop
  with `sleep 1`) does not return any failures.
- No errors found in samba / winbind logs.
- Configuration seems to be okay (otherwise it would always fail).
- Issue also exists on default GNOME environment

## krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 MY.DOMAIN.COM = {
  # KDC is the key distribution server
  # One per line in the format
  #kdc = ##adsrv##
  ##KDCSERVER##
   kdc = dc1.my.domain.com
   kdc = dc2.my.domain.com
   kdc = dc3.my.domain.com
   kdc = dc4.my.domain.com
   kdc = dc5.my.domain.com

  # Admin server is a list of AD server
  #admin_server = adsrv1 adsrv2 ... adsrvX
  ##ADMINSERVER##
   admin_server =  dc1.my.domain.com dc2.my.domain.com dc3.my.domain.com dc4.my.domain.com dc5.my.domain.com

 }

##MyRealms##

[domain_realm]
 .my.domain.com = MY.DOMAIN.COM
 my.domain.com = MY.DOMAIN.COM

##MyDomRealms##
```

## smb.conf

```
[global]
server string = my server
workgroup = MY
security = ads
realm = my.domain.com
password server = *
domain logons = no
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
winbind enum groups = no
winbind enum users = no
winbind use default domain = yes
domain master = no
local master = no
prefered master = no
os level = 0
idmap config *:backend = tdb
idmap config *:range = 11000-20000
idmap config MY:backend = rid
idmap config MY:range = 100000-200000
```